# "&>" and "<&" token questions

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, io

I'm a little confused about the <& and >& tokens and I've included an example with my question. On the bottom of my example, couldn't I just use <3 and >4 as arguments to cat? I know you can't because I've tried it but I just don't understand why not? I'm not duplicating file descriptors 3 and 4, I'm just trying to redirect input and out put from file descriptors 3 and 4. Why do I have to include the ampersand symbols in those two tokens?

```
#!/bin/bash

case $# in

    0)
        exec 3<&0 4<&1
        ;;

    1)
        exec 3< $1 4<&1
        ;;

    2)
        exec 3< $1 4> $2
        ;;

    *)
        echo "bad"
        return 1
        ;; 

esac

cat <&3 >&4

exec 3<&- 4<&-
```

Answer (score 1):

`< myfile` will read from a file named `myfile`

`<4` will similarly read from a file named `4`

The rules are straight forward:

- If you have filenames, you should use the file opening operators `<` and `>`
- If you have file descriptors, you should use the FD copying operators `<&` and `>&`

It may help to note that `<&` is a completely separate operator. It is not `<` applied to anything.

Comment: But what about in case 2 where we have 3< $1 and 4> $2, these are file descriptors and we don't have ampersand included. Also, why are there spaces after greater and less then symbols?

Comment: They're not existing file descriptors. They're just where you store the result of opening the filename "$1". If you instead wanted to copy an existing fd, you would use `<&`.